# How do you handle the order of functions in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mean

So I have an Angular component.

With some array objects containing data I want to work with:

```
  books: Book[] = [];
  reviews: Review[] = [];
```

This is what my ngOnInit() looks like:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.retrieveBooks();
    this.retrieveReviews();
    this.setRatingToTen();
  }
```

With this I write Books, and Reviews to object arrays.
This is done through a "subscription" to data through services:

```
  retrieveBooks(): void {
    this.bookService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.books = data;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }

  retrieveReviews(): void {
    this.reviewService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.reviews = data;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

So this next function I have is just an example of "working with the data".

In this example, I just want to change all of the totalratings to 10 for each Book:

```
  setRatingToTen(): void {
    this.books.forEach(element => {
      element.totalrating = 10;
    });
    console.log(this.books);
  }
```

The problem I have been trying to wrap my head around is this:

**this.books** is an **empty array**.

I THINK the reason is because this function is running before the data subscription.

IF this is the case, then my understanding of ngOnInit must not be right.

I thought it would call the function in order.

Maybe that's still the case, it's just that they don't complete in order.

So my questions are:

**1. Why is it an empty array?**

(was I right? or is there more to it?)

**2. How do Angular developers write functions so they operate in a desired order?**

(since the data needs to be there so I can work with it, how do I avoid this issue?)

**(3.) BONUS question:**

(if you have the time, please and thank you)

My goal is to pull this.reviews.rating for each book where this.reviews.title equals this.books.title, get an average score; and then overwrite the "0" placeholder of this.books.totalrating with the average. How could I re-write the setRatingToTen() function to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one of solution using **forkJoin** method in rxjs .

you can check this for details https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61

Working demo : [enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pht1qw)

**ngOnInit:**

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.requestDataFromMultipleSources().subscribe(resList => {
        this.books = resList[0];
        this.reviews = resList[1];
        this.setRatingToTen(this.books,this.reviews);
    })
}
```

**forkJoin method:**

```
public requestDataFromMultipleSources(): Observable<any[]> {
    let response1 = this.retrieveBooks();
    let response2 = this.retrieveReviews();
    // Observable.forkJoin (RxJS 5) changes to just forkJoin() in RxJS 6
    return forkJoin([response1, response2]);
  }
```

**Other methods:**

```
retrieveBooks(): void {
    this.bookService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.books = data;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }

  retrieveReviews(): void {
    this.reviewService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.reviews = data;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
  
  setRatingToTen(books, reviews): void {
    this.books.forEach(element => {
      element.totalrating = 10;
    });
    console.log(this.books);
  }
```

Comment: this.requestDataFromMultipleSources().subscribe(resList => { On this line I receive the error message: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Comment: I hope you dint miss importing forkJoin import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

Comment: Nope, it's there. The only thing I changed was this.setRatingToTen(this.games, this.reviews), because the comma was a period and I thought this was an obvious typo.

Comment: Could you please help me with sharing the working code ion codesandbox or stackblitz?

Comment: Okay, looking over it to see why mine doesn't work. Could it have something to do with my service returning Review[] and Book[] objects instead of json?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218064/discussion-between-harmandeep-singh-kalsi-and-labrapoo).

Comment: @labrapoo , there was some question . sorry i could not understand
```
Any time I want to do anything dynamically from this component, should it put inside of the this.requestDataFromMultipleSources().subscribe function?
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular makes heavy use of **observables** to handle variety of **asynchronous** operations. Making server side requests (through HTTP) is one of those.

Your first two questions clearly reflect you are ignoring the **asynchronous nature of observables**.

> Observables are **lazy** **Push collections** of **multiple values**. [detailed link](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable)

Means observable response would be pushed over time in an asynchronous way. You can not guarantee which of the two distinct functions would return its response first.

Having said that, **rxjs** library (Observables are also part of this library and angular borrowed them from here) provides a rich collection of **operators** that you can use to **manipulate observables**.

With the above explanation, here is one by one answer to your questions.

**1. Why is it an empty array?**

Because you are thinking in terms of synchronous sequential flow of code, where one method would get called only after the other has finished with its working. But here **retrieveBooks** and **retrieveReviews** both are making **asynchronous** (observable) calls and then subscribing to it. This means there is no guarantee when their response would be received. Meanwhile the hit to **setRatingToTen** had already been made, at that point in time **books** array was empty.

**2. How do Angular developers write functions so they operate in a desired order?**

Angular developer would understand the nature of **asynchronous observable** calls, and would **pipe** the operators in an order so that they are sure they have the response in hand before performing any further operation on the observable stream.

**(3.) BONUS question:**

Your requirement specifies that you must first have the response of both observables at hand before performing any action. For that **forkJoin** rxjs operator suits your need. Documentation for this operator say

> One common use case for this is if you wish to issue multiple requests on page load (or some other event) and only want to take action when a response has been received for all. [detailed link](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin)

Not sure about your average score strategy, but here is an example code how you would achieve your purpose.

```js
ngOnInit(){
let req1$ = this.bookService.getAll();
let req2$ = this.reviewService.getAll();
forkJoin(req1$, req2$).subscribe(([response1, response2])=>{
for(let book of response1) //loop through book array first
{
 for(let review of response2) //inner loop of reviews
{
if(book.title == review.title)
{
//complete your logic here..
}
}

}
  });

}
```